# Remove LF from the last line in file

Tags: scala, vim, haskell, sed, awk

The last line of my file should not have the LF as last character.

In vim I can do

```
:set noendofline binary
:wq
```

see http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format#Terminator_after_last_line

How can I do that with a sed oneliner filter for a longer pipe?

Any other tool (headless vim? awk) is ok to me. no perl pls.

How about scala or haskell !?

Comment: what kind of file is it? text, binary? how was it created? is it the only LF in the file?

Comment: Does it matter? simply remove the very last LF. Assume it is binary, but in fact it is xml text.

Comment: In fact I want to strip all whitespace (including LF) around an opening and an ending tag of some xml.

Comment: `sed` works on lines (and some versions of `sed` have limits on how long those lines can be); lines end with LF, including the last line in the file.  I don't think you're going to find that `sed` is the right tool for this job.  Since I'd use Perl, I can't help, though you could probably use Python instead.

Comment: sorry about that perl comment of mine :-) But that language is simply outdated and I dont want to learn it anymore ...

Comment: Scala lacks of memory usage on big files, if you use language inproperly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to lose all newlines, the following works:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0}'
```

You could also use `tr -d '\012'` to delete LF (NL) characters; it is probably faster than `awk` for the job.

With a more elaborate `awk` script, you could keep all newlines except the last if that's what you want:

```
awk '{if (NR>1) print old; old=$0;} END { printf "%s", old }'
```

(You can't do *that* with `tr`!)  Both these `awk` scripts can be plugged into a pipeline.  I don't know if `awk` will handle humongous 'single-line' files, but it probably will handle them OK.  Remember that many Unix tools are based around lines — beware of pushing them too hard, and test carefully before putting into production.

Comment: A slightly different way to write it would be `awk -v old="" 'NR>1 { print old; old=$0 } END { printf "%s", old }'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `head` to get all bytes except the last one:

```
head -c $(($(stat -c %s file.txt)-1)) file.txt
```

In `python`:

```
python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(sys.stdin.read()[:-1])' <file.txt
```

Comment: getting closer: howto use that in a pipe? the reference to the fname is not nice ...

Comment: @Bastl, `xargs` can get you there, even for one item: `echo file.txt | xargs -I FILE bash -c 'head -c $(( $(stat -c %s FILE) - 1 )) FILE'`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't as simple as it looks. You can use this awk(1) filter:

```
awk ' { if(l) { print line; } line=$0; l=1; } END { if(l) printf("%s", line); }'
```

In a nutshell: It reads line by line. If one line (= `l` is true) has already been read, it prints it and remembers the next line. At the end, the last line is printed without line feed.

You could achieve the same with sed(1) it you could make it treat the input as a single line but I couldn't find an option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically ask for a Haskell version, here is one that uses `ByteString`s, operating on stdin and stdout:

```
import Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Internal (c2w)
import Data.Word

main :: IO ()
main = B.interact removeLastLF

lf :: Word8
lf = c2w '\n'

removeLastLF :: ByteString -> ByteString
removeLastLF xs | B.last xs == lf = B.init xs
                | otherwise       = xs
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick in Haskell:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)
main = interact (intercalate "\n" . lines)
```

Comment: What? Why? That can add a newline, but not remove. Did you mean to call `init`?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply cat through tr:

```
cat filename | tr -d "\n" > filename.nonl
```

Comment: that would remove all lines, I just wanted the last one.